systemd-239 not installing rsyslog SystemLogSocketName
I have a system with Redhat7.9 where rsyslog is receiving journald logs via /run/systemd/journal/syslog. This is configured by the file located under /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf.
$  cat /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog

$  ll /run/systemd/journal/syslog
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Apr  4 22:32 /run/systemd/journal/syslog

On Redhat8 I noticed that this config file is missing, and the aforementioned socket is not present
 #  cat /etc/redhat-release
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.8 (Ootpa)

 #    cat /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.con
 cat: /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.con: No such file or directory

This file is provided by systemd package.
 $  yum whatprovides /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf
 systemd-219-57.0.1.el7.x86_64 : A System and Service Manager
 Matched from:
 Filename    : /etc/rsyslog.d/listen.conf

I cannot find any reference as to why this config file is no longer shipped by systemd. Anyone came across this?
